# tkinter entry given and button pressed yet doesn't register the text as a file even if named and spelled correctly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

```
import pyautogui
import time
import tkinter

#rewrites a certain text (its for a video idea)


def openandtypewrite():
    # time.sleep(10)
    textfile = open(entry_file, 'r')
    for word in textfile:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Typewriter")

label = tkinter.Label(root, text="File Name:")
label.grid(row=1, column=1)

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=1, column=2)


entry_file = entry.get()


button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Typewrite", command=openandtypewrite)
button.grid(row=2, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when the entry is given and the button is pressed i get an error message saying:

```
File "c:\Users\eugen\OneDrive\Desktop\CODES\Whatsapp-spam-bot\gui-spam.py", line 14, in openandspam
    textfile = open(entry_file, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

even though I entered a text it doesnt know what it is and thinks i wrote nothing in the entry file

did i make a mistake in the get()  command? pls tell me how to fix this!

Comment: You're getting the value from the entry widget about a millisecond after creating it. The user won't have even seen the entry widget, much less have a chance to type anything.

Comment: how could i fix that then?

Comment: call the `get` method immediately before you need the value: inside of `openandtypewrite`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

all i had to do is trigger the get() command on the press of the button so i just moved it into the custom command!